# Highcharts breaks after getting a variable's value with document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I created a chart with Highcharts and it works very well, you can see it in action here:

```js
/*Getting Data*/
var dataQuantity = [8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 27786, 30589, 27989, 28141, 28141, 28141, 28141];

var dataMv = [19.69, 19.69, 19.69, 19.69, 19.69, 19.69, 19.69, 19.69, 19.69, 19.69, 19.69, 16.66, 16.06, 16.66, 16.66, 16.66, 16.66, 16.66];

var dataDate = [1501457113, 1501459513, 1501461913, 1501464313, 1501466713, 1501469113, 1501471513, 1501473913, 1501476313, 1501478713, 1501481113, 1501483513, 1501485913, 1501488313, 1501490713, 1501493113, 1501495513, 1501497913];



var myChart = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
  myChart = Highcharts.chart('chart', {
    chart: {
      type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: dataDate
    },
    yAxis: [{
      title: {
        text: 'Market Value'
      }
    }, {
      title: {
        text: 'Quantity'
      },
      opposite: true
    }],
    series: [{
      name: 'Market Value',
      yAxis: 0,
      data: dataMv
    }, {
      name: 'Quantity',
      yAxis: 1,
      data: dataQuantity
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

My problem is that my website is in PHP, so the way I pass my data into javascript is by echoing it in a non displaying  and getting the value out of it with javascript. I tried doing it, but it failed:

```js
/*Getting Data*/
var dataQuantity = [8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 27786, 30589, 27989, 28141, 28141, 28141, 28141];

var dataMv = document.getElementById('JSON-mv').innerHTML;

var dataDate = [1501457113, 1501459513, 1501461913, 1501464313, 1501466713, 1501469113, 1501471513, 1501473913, 1501476313, 1501478713, 1501481113, 1501483513, 1501485913, 1501488313, 1501490713, 1501493113, 1501495513, 1501497913];



var myChart = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
  myChart = Highcharts.chart('chart', {
    chart: {
      type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: dataDate
    },
    yAxis: [{
      title: {
        text: 'Market Value'
      }
    }, {
      title: {
        text: 'Quantity'
      },
      opposite: true
    }],
    series: [{
      name: 'Market Value',
      yAxis: 0,
      data: dataMv
    }, {
      name: 'Quantity',
      yAxis: 1,
      data: dataQuantity
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="JSON-mv" style="display:none;">[19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,16.66,16.06,16.66,16.66,16.66,16.66,16.66]</div>
<div id="chart" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

The only thing I did differently is that I used

```
var dataMv = document.getElementById('JSON-mv').innerHTML;
```

and with it the value of dataMv should be the same as if I just declared it as dataMv = [x,y,z] or is it different?

Comment: Is your script *behind* the html element? If not, use a DOMContentLoaded handler

Comment: No, it was in the <html>, but I tried console.log(dataMv) and the data showed up in the console. I moved the script after the </html> tag, but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

if you directly use `document.getElementById('JSON-mv').innerHTML` its of type string so your chart is breaking convert to array and should work fine one quick way is this

```
    var dataQuantity = [8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 8327, 27786, 30589, 27989, 28141, 28141, 28141, 28141];
    var dataMv = document.getElementById('JSON-mv').innerHTML;
    dataMv = dataMv.replace('[','');
    dataMv = dataMv.replace(']','');
    dataMv = dataMv.split(',');
    var dataDate = [1501457113, 1501459513, 1501461913, 1501464313, 1501466713, 1501469113, 1501471513, 1501473913, 1501476313, 1501478713, 1501481113, 1501483513, 1501485913, 1501488313, 1501490713, 1501493113, 1501495513, 1501497913];
    var myChart = null;
    $(document).ready(function() {
      myChart = Highcharts.chart('chart', {
        chart: {
          type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
          text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: dataDate
        },
        yAxis: [{
          title: {
            text: 'Market Value'
          }
        }, {
          title: {
            text: 'Quantity'
          },
          opposite: true
        }],
        series: [{
          name: 'Market Value',
          yAxis: 0,
          data: dataMv
        }, {
          name: 'Quantity',
          yAxis: 1,
          data: dataQuantity
        }]
      });
    });

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="JSON-mv" style="display:none;">[19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,16.66,16.06,16.66,16.66,16.66,16.66,16.66]</div>
    <div id="chart" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: When I use this method the output is    ["[19.69", "19.69", ... , "16.66", "16.66", "16.66]"]  so before the split(),  substr() or something  should be used to remove the first and last character '[' and ']'

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/FRhjn6G.png
The blue line is not shown, which is the line of the Market Value, from the data of the div

Comment: Found the problem: if you wrap the numbers in dataQuantity in quotes so they become a string they won't show up on the chart (try it with the first ~3) so in addition we need to convert all elements of dataMv from string to int/float

Comment: `var dataMv2 = dataMv.map(Number);` and then I called dataMv2 in the chart and it works perfectly!
https://jsfiddle.net/2Ltybwfb/

Comment: Btw. you are defining Highcharts twice, and getting error #16 (www.highcharts.com/errors/16). Get rid of the Highcharts script from the External Resources section: https://jsfiddle.net/c57oudLm/.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting that data in a div, make it the value of a hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" id="JSON-mv" value="[19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,19.69,16.66,16.06,16.66,16.66,16.66,16.66,16.66]">
```